# Using a ref to get a size of a functional react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm running React 16.8, I have a functional component that I need to measure the height of (so i can know how many children to display in the vertical space), looks like the best way to do so is with refs, but everything I've attempted so far results in the same warning: `Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?`.

I've tried following examples online to use .forwardRef but I must not be setting it up correctly. Any help appreciated.

Here's the relevant code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

const ForwardingStyledDayGrid = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <StyledDayGrid ref={ref}>{props.children}</StyledDayGrid>
))

function DayGrid(props) {

  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0)

  const dayGridRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    setHeight(dayGridRef.current.clientHeight)
  })

  return (
    <ForwardingStyledDayGrid
      ref={dayGridRef}
      inCurrentMonth={props.inCurrentMonth}

    >
      {children}
    </ForwardingStyledDayGrid>
  )
}

export default DayGrid
```

and here's StyledDayGrid:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import withTheme from '@material-ui/core/styles/withTheme'

import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'

const StyledDayGrid = withTheme(styled(({ inCurrentMonth, ...rest }) => (
  <Grid {...rest} />
))`
  && {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: ${props =>
      !props.inCurrentMonth && props.theme.monthView.nonCurrentMonth};
    etc.....
  }
`)
```

Comment: I would check that StyledDayGrid is also forwarding the ref

Comment: What is StyledDayGrid?

Comment: I was JUST looking into wether or not i need to forward refs to StyledDayGrid (a MUI Grid component imported and styled with styled components), I will look into that and report back!

Answer (score 1):

As per the warning, and as explained in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#refs-and-function-components), Functional components don't support the `ref` attribute as they don't have instances like class components.

You are on the correct path with `forwardRef`, however, it needs to be used on the Function Component directly, in this case `StyledDayGrid` e.g.

```
const StyledDayGrid = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  // use 'ref' internally
  return (...);
});

function DayGrid(props) {

  const dayGridRef = useRef(null)
  ...
  return (
    <StyledDayGrid ref={dayGridRef}>
      {children}
    </StyledDayGrid>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks James, StyledDayGrid is a styled component MUI import, do I need to forward the ref to the styled component?

Comment: @katy6514 hmm in that case `ref` was never going to work because, as I say, Function components can't use ref. Can you link me to the docs for said component? This doesn't appear to be a standard component.